# Why does this spice simulation produce a strange output?

Tags: ltspice, cmos

I tried to design a CMOS inverter in LayoutEditor schematic editor and tried to simulate the generated spice file on LTSpice and the resulting output was not what I expected. For the simple DC sweep of the input voltage, the output should transition from 5 to 0 at a threshold voltage).

However, the same netlist with simpler (level 3) MOSFET models produce the output I expected, so that rules out any problem with the spice file syntax. 
I'm not sure if the issue is with the model given by LayoutEditor or the way LTSpice handles the level=54 model. (Models for NMOS_VTL and PMOS_VTL  from the spicemodel.sp file is attached)

As per my understanding, level of a MOSFET model indicates the number of parameters it specifies, therefore the higher level models can be adapted to match the physical device much more accurately.

*ltspice /Users/chamod/Documents/Layout Editor/inv-1/inv-2/inv-2.les generated by the LayoutEditor (www.LayoutEditor.net)

```
*start of netlist
V1 vcc 0 5
MMP1 vcc input output vcc PMOS_VTL W=1u L=1u
MMN1 output input 0 0 NMOS_VTL W=1u L=1u
V2 input 0 0

*LTspice specific part

*end of netlist

.dc v2 0 5
*required models
.include /Applications/layout.app/Contents/library/openCellLibrary/spicemodel.sp
```

[image: LayoutEditor Schematic]

[image: LTSpice output waveform]

NMOS Model given with LayoutEditor:

```
* Customized PTM 45 NMOS

.model  NMOS_VTL  nmos  level = 54

+version = 4.0    binunit = 1    paramchk= 1    mobmod  = 0
+capmod  = 2      igcmod  = 1    igbmod  = 1    geomod  = 1
+diomod  = 1      rdsmod  = 0    rbodymod= 1    rgatemod= 1
+permod  = 1      acnqsmod= 0    trnqsmod= 0

* parameters related to the technology node
+tnom = 27    epsrox = 3.9
+eta0 = 0.0049    nfactor = 2.1    wint = 5e-09
+cgso = 1.1e-10    cgdo = 1.1e-10    xl = -2e-08

* parameters customized by the user
+toxe = 1.75e-09    toxp = 1.1e-09    toxm = 1.75e-09    toxref = 1.75e-09
+dtox = 6.5e-10    lint = 3.75e-09
+vth0 = 0.471    k1 = 0.53    u0 = 0.04359    vsat = 147390
+rdsw = 155    ndep = 3.3e+18    xj = 1.4e-08

* secondary parameters
+ll      = 0            wl      = 0            lln     = 1            wln     = 1          
+lw      = 0            ww      = 0            lwn     = 1            wwn     = 1          
+lwl     = 0            wwl     = 0            xpart   = 0               
+k2      = 0.01         k3      = 0          
+k3b     = 0            w0      = 2.5e-006     dvt0    = 1            dvt1    = 2       
+dvt2    = -0.032       dvt0w   = 0            dvt1w   = 0            dvt2w   = 0          
+dsub    = 0.1          minv    = 0.05         voffl   = 0            dvtp0   = 1.0e-009     
+dvtp1   = 0.1          lpe0    = 0            lpeb    = 0               
+ngate   = 2e+020       nsd     = 2e+020       phin    = 0          
+cdsc    = 0.000        cdscb   = 0            cdscd   = 0            cit     = 0          
+voff    = -0.13        etab    = 0          
+vfb     = -0.55        ua      = 6e-010       ub      = 1.2e-018     
+uc      = 0            a0      = 1.0          ags     = 1e-020     
+a1      = 0            a2      = 1.0          b0      = 0            b1      = 0          
+keta    = 0.04         dwg     = 0            dwb     = 0            pclm    = 0.04       
+pdiblc1 = 0.001        pdiblc2 = 0.001        pdiblcb = -0.005       drout   = 0.5        
+pvag    = 1e-020       delta   = 0.01         pscbe1  = 8.14e+008    pscbe2  = 1e-007     
+fprout  = 0.2          pdits   = 0.08         pditsd  = 0.23         pditsl  = 2.3e+006   
+rsh     = 5            rsw     = 85           rdw     = 85        
+rdswmin = 0            rdwmin  = 0            rswmin  = 0            prwg    = 0          
+prwb    = 6.8e-011     wr      = 1            alpha0  = 0.074        alpha1  = 0.005      
+beta0   = 30           agidl   = 0.0002       bgidl   = 2.1e+009     cgidl   = 0.0002     
+egidl   = 0.8          

+aigbacc = 0.012        bigbacc = 0.0028       cigbacc = 0.002     
+nigbacc = 1            aigbinv = 0.014        bigbinv = 0.004        cigbinv = 0.004      
+eigbinv = 1.1          nigbinv = 3            aigc    = 0.012        bigc    = 0.0028     
+cigc    = 0.002        aigsd   = 0.012        bigsd   = 0.0028       cigsd   = 0.002     
+nigc    = 1            poxedge = 1            pigcd   = 1            ntox    = 1          

+xrcrg1  = 12           xrcrg2  = 5          
+cgbo    = 2.56e-011    cgdl    = 2.653e-10     
+cgsl    = 2.653e-10    ckappas = 0.03         ckappad = 0.03         acde    = 1          
+moin    = 15           noff    = 0.9          voffcv  = 0.02       

+kt1     = -0.11        kt1l    = 0            kt2     = 0.022        ute     = -1.5       
+ua1     = 4.31e-009    ub1     = 7.61e-018    uc1     = -5.6e-011    prt     = 0          
+at      = 33000      

+fnoimod = 1            tnoimod = 0          

+jss     = 0.0001       jsws    = 1e-011       jswgs   = 1e-010       njs     = 1          
+ijthsfwd= 0.01         ijthsrev= 0.001        bvs     = 10           xjbvs   = 1          
+jsd     = 0.0001       jswd    = 1e-011       jswgd   = 1e-010       njd     = 1          
+ijthdfwd= 0.01         ijthdrev= 0.001        bvd     = 10           xjbvd   = 1          
+pbs     = 1            cjs     = 0.0005       mjs     = 0.5          pbsws   = 1          
+cjsws   = 5e-010       mjsws   = 0.33         pbswgs  = 1            cjswgs  = 3e-010     
+mjswgs  = 0.33         pbd     = 1            cjd     = 0.0005       mjd     = 0.5        
+pbswd   = 1            cjswd   = 5e-010       mjswd   = 0.33         pbswgd  = 1          
+cjswgd  = 5e-010       mjswgd  = 0.33         tpb     = 0.005        tcj     = 0.001      
+tpbsw   = 0.005        tcjsw   = 0.001        tpbswg  = 0.005        tcjswg  = 0.001      
+xtis    = 3            xtid    = 3          

+dmcg    = 0e-006       dmci    = 0e-006       dmdg    = 0e-006       dmcgt   = 0e-007     
+dwj     = 0.0e-008     xgw     = 0e-007       xgl     = 0e-008     

+rshg    = 0.4          gbmin   = 1e-010       rbpb    = 5            rbpd    = 15         
+rbps    = 15           rbdb    = 15           rbsb    = 15           ngcon   = 1          


.model  PMOS_VTL  pmos  level = 54

+version = 4.0    binunit = 1    paramchk= 1    mobmod  = 0
+capmod  = 2      igcmod  = 1    igbmod  = 1    geomod  = 1
+diomod  = 1      rdsmod  = 0    rbodymod= 1    rgatemod= 1
+permod  = 1      acnqsmod= 0    trnqsmod= 0

* parameters related to the technology node
+tnom = 27    epsrox = 3.9
+eta0 = 0.0049    nfactor = 2.1    wint = 5e-09
+cgso = 1.1e-10    cgdo = 1.1e-10    xl = -2e-08

* parameters customized by the user
+toxe = 1.85e-09    toxp = 1.1e-09    toxm = 1.85e-09    toxref = 1.85e-09
+dtox = 7.5e-10    lint = 3.75e-09
+vth0 = -0.423    k1 = 0.491    u0 = 0.00432    vsat = 70000
+rdsw = 155    ndep = 2.54e+18    xj = 1.4e-08

*secondary parameters
+ll      = 0            wl      = 0            lln     = 1            wln     = 1          
+lw      = 0            ww      = 0            lwn     = 1            wwn     = 1          
+lwl     = 0            wwl     = 0            xpart   = 0               
+k2      = -0.01        k3      = 0          
+k3b     = 0            w0      = 2.5e-006     dvt0    = 1            dvt1    = 2       
+dvt2    = -0.032       dvt0w   = 0            dvt1w   = 0            dvt2w   = 0          
+dsub    = 0.1          minv    = 0.05         voffl   = 0            dvtp0   = 1e-009     
+dvtp1   = 0.05         lpe0    = 0            lpeb    = 0               
+ngate   = 2e+020       nsd     = 2e+020       phin    = 0          
+cdsc    = 0.000        cdscb   = 0            cdscd   = 0            cit     = 0          
+voff    = -0.126       etab    = 0          
+vfb     = 0.55         ua      = 2.0e-009     ub      = 0.5e-018     
+uc      = 0            a0      = 1.0          ags     = 1e-020     
+a1      = 0            a2      = 1            b0      = -1e-020      b1      = 0          
+keta    = -0.047       dwg     = 0            dwb     = 0            pclm    = 0.12       
+pdiblc1 = 0.001        pdiblc2 = 0.001        pdiblcb = 3.4e-008     drout   = 0.56       
+pvag    = 1e-020       delta   = 0.01         pscbe1  = 8.14e+008    pscbe2  = 9.58e-007  
+fprout  = 0.2          pdits   = 0.08         pditsd  = 0.23         pditsl  = 2.3e+006   
+rsh     = 5            rsw     = 85           rdw     = 85        
+rdswmin = 0            rdwmin  = 0            rswmin  = 0            prwg    = 3.22e-008  
+prwb    = 6.8e-011     wr      = 1            alpha0  = 0.074        alpha1  = 0.005      
+beta0   = 30           agidl   = 0.0002       bgidl   = 2.1e+009     cgidl   = 0.0002     
+egidl   = 0.8          

+aigbacc = 0.012        bigbacc = 0.0028       cigbacc = 0.002     
+nigbacc = 1            aigbinv = 0.014        bigbinv = 0.004        cigbinv = 0.004      
+eigbinv = 1.1          nigbinv = 3            aigc    = 0.69         bigc    = 0.0012     
+cigc    = 0.0008       aigsd   = 0.0087       bigsd   = 0.0012       cigsd   = 0.0008     
+nigc    = 1            poxedge = 1            pigcd   = 1            ntox    = 1 

+xrcrg1  = 12           xrcrg2  = 5          
+cgbo    = 2.56e-011    cgdl    = 2.653e-10
+cgsl    = 2.653e-10    ckappas = 0.03         ckappad = 0.03         acde    = 1
+moin    = 15           noff    = 0.9          voffcv  = 0.02

+kt1     = -0.11        kt1l    = 0            kt2     = 0.022        ute     = -1.5       
+ua1     = 4.31e-009    ub1     = 7.61e-018    uc1     = -5.6e-011    prt     = 0          
+at      = 33000      

+fnoimod = 1            tnoimod = 0          

+jss     = 0.0001       jsws    = 1e-011       jswgs   = 1e-010       njs     = 1          
+ijthsfwd= 0.01         ijthsrev= 0.001        bvs     = 10           xjbvs   = 1          
+jsd     = 0.0001       jswd    = 1e-011       jswgd   = 1e-010       njd     = 1          
+ijthdfwd= 0.01         ijthdrev= 0.001        bvd     = 10           xjbvd   = 1          
+pbs     = 1            cjs     = 0.0005       mjs     = 0.5          pbsws   = 1          
+cjsws   = 5e-010       mjsws   = 0.33         pbswgs  = 1            cjswgs  = 3e-010     
+mjswgs  = 0.33         pbd     = 1            cjd     = 0.0005       mjd     = 0.5        
+pbswd   = 1            cjswd   = 5e-010       mjswd   = 0.33         pbswgd  = 1          
+cjswgd  = 5e-010       mjswgd  = 0.33         tpb     = 0.005        tcj     = 0.001      
+tpbsw   = 0.005        tcjsw   = 0.001        tpbswg  = 0.005        tcjswg  = 0.001      
+xtis    = 3            xtid    = 3          

+dmcg    = 0e-006       dmci    = 0e-006       dmdg    = 0e-006       dmcgt   = 0e-007     
+dwj     = 0.0e-008     xgw     = 0e-007       xgl     = 0e-008     

+rshg    = 0.4          gbmin   = 1e-010       rbpb    = 5            rbpd    = 15         
+rbps    = 15           rbdb    = 15           rbsb    = 15           ngcon   = 1
```

LTSpice output log:

```
Circuit: *ltspice /Users/chamod/Documents/Layout Editor/inv-1/inv-2/inv-2.les generated by the LayoutEditor (www.LayoutEditor.net)

Warning: toxe, toxp and dtox all given and toxe != toxp + dtox; dtox ignored.
Direct Newton iteration failed to find .op point.  (Use ".option noopiter" to skip.)
Starting Gmin stepping
Gmin = 10
Gmin = 1.07374
Gmin = 0.115292
Gmin = 0.0123794
Gmin = 0.00132923
Gmin = 0.000142725
Gmin = 1.5325e-05
Gmin = 1.6455e-06
Gmin = 1.76685e-07
Gmin = 1.89714e-08
Gmin = 2.03704e-09
Gmin = 2.18725e-10
Gmin = 2.34854e-11
Gmin = 2.52173e-12
Gmin = 2.70769e-13
Gmin = 0
Gmin stepping succeeded in finding the operating point.


Date: Sun Nov 26 22:17:00 2017
Total elapsed time: 0.179 seconds.

tnom = 27
temp = 27
method = trap
totiter = 2541
traniter = 0
tranpoints = 0
accept = 0
rejected = 0
matrix size = 13
fillins = 0
solver = Normal
Matrix Compiler1:      57 opcodes  0.2/[0.1]/0.2
Matrix Compiler2: off
```

Comment: I don't see any properly defined question. And I'm also not  sure what "Level 54" means.

Comment: Did you read the LTSpice help file page on mosfets? As far as I can see, only level 1, 2, and 3 and an LTSpice proprietary "VDMOS" model are supported.

Comment: Was there any error message in the output when trying to simulate the "level 54" model?

Comment: @ThePhoton No errors, but there were warnings about some floating nodes. I manually edited the spice netlist and updated the question.

Comment: @ThePhoton I assumed that(LTSpice manual not including the level 54) won't be an issue as LayoutEditor software had a dedicated menu for "LTSpice->Simulate+waveform viewer"

Comment: What I see in that schematic is not a CMOS inverter: in a CMOS inverter the source of the PMOS is connected to Vdd and the drains of the two devices are connected to the output. Your PMOS seems to have source and drain terminals swapped.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Oh I didn't notice it. Output didn't change after correcting though.

Comment: You only posted the NMOS model `NMOS_VTL`. What about `PMOS_VTL`? You should post it as well. We don't have the same library as you have.

Comment: Added the PMOS model in the edit

Comment: I can confirm I can reproduce the issue. With a DC operating point analysis, Vcc=5V and Vinput=5V I get 8.11V at the output. It goes beyond the positive rail! WEIRD! I can only assume some parameter in the level 54 model is set incorrectly. BTW it seems that LTspice supports a level 54 model, but it is undocumented (see [this](http://www.amarketplaceofideas.com/a-180-nanometer-mosfet-model-using-tsmc-transistor-models-from-mosis-in-lt-spice.htm)).